# How to work jquery autocomplete with select tag ?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

How to work jquery autocomplete with select tag ?

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="search" onkeydown="autoCompleteByTag(this)"  name="data[search]" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">

<select id="search_type"  onchange="autoCompleteByTag(this)" name="data[search_type]">
<option value="new">New</option>
<option value="old">Old</option>
</select>
```

Here `input#search` field autocomplete is working fine, but how to work autocomplete of this `input` tag with select box .
i.e when onchange of `select#search_type`, autocomplete function need to done in `input#search` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by function on

Html

```
<select id="search_type"  onchange="changeOnType()" name="data[search_type]">
```

Javascript

```
function changeOnType() {
    $('#search').autocomplete( "search",  $('#search').val() );
}
```

So the `input#search` is triggered here from `changeOnType()`  and autocomplete list will dropdown in `input#search` field

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code and I'm not sure of what you are trying to achieve. The idea behind the auto-complete functionality in jQuery is to speed up input when you are looking at a long list of possible input elements. Such as a look-up for UK place names, or football teams etc, which would have a SELECT drop down list to cumbersome to navigate.

If you have only two elements in the SELECT drop down, then an auto-complete isn't the best solution. If you have more elements and the code shown was merely an example, then once again you need to be more specific.

I'll go out on a limb here and suggest that you are trying to use the SELECT drop down box to limit the input value derived from this input type, and using the auto-complete to speed up the selection process.

Comment: SELECT drop down box is used get different types in results seperately. It is not used to limit the results.